# How to autofill data when I enter a certain value in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

As can be seen from the image above, I have a table which has three columns, I want to make it so that when I enter the job number in another spreadsheet, the name and location columns automatically fill those cells. So it should automatically fill the columns name and location when I for example enter 1. The data that i want it to be filled with is in the table next to it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below formula BUT first fix the ranges:

Name Formula:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,E2:G6,2,0)`

Location Formulas:

`=VLOOKUP(A2,E2:G6,3,0)`

Result:

[image]